# Syntax error (1064) in line 2

Tags: mysql, database, syntax-error

I'm trying to save a queried table into another table. My new table is already created with the following structure:

```
TABLE: edit_mdr
+---------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
|Column         | Type           | Comment                         |
+---------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| ID            | int(10)        | unsigned zerofill Auto Increment|
+---------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| date_submitted| date           |                                 |
+---------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| requestor     | varchar(40)    |                                 |
+---------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| campus        | varchar(10)    |                                 | 
+---------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| defect_loc    | varchar(40)    |                                 |
+---------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| defect_des    | varchar(1500)  |                                 |
+---------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| priority      | varchar(10)    |                                 |
+---------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| action_taken  | varchar(1500)  |                                 |
+---------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| assigned_to   | varchar(40)    |                                 |
+---------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| category      | varchar(30)    |                                 |
+---------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| photo         | varchar(200)   |                                 |
+---------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| status        | varchar(10)    |                                 |
+---------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
```

The query is as follows:

```
MySQL Query:
INSERT INTO edit_mdr (date_submitted, requestor, campus, defect_loc, defect_des, priority, action_taken, assigned_to, category, photo, status) 
    VALUES(SELECT submit_time,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-name',     field_value, NULL)) AS requestor,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'menu-campus',   field_value, NULL)) AS campus,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'location',      field_value, NULL)) AS defect_loc,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-message',  field_value, NULL)) AS defect_des,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'menu-priority', field_value, NULL)) AS priority,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'work_done',     field_value, NULL)) AS action_taken,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'assigned-to',   field_value, NULL)) AS assigned_to,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'category',      field_value, NULL)) AS category,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'file-photo',    field_value, NULL)) AS photo,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'status',        field_value, NULL)) AS status
FROM
    wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits
GROUP BY
    submit_time);
```

The error returned is

> Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'SELECT submit_time,
>   MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-name', field_value, NULL)' at line 2

I have no idea what's going on with the 2nd line so called error.... Pls help!

Comment: You should read the `INSERT` syntax. You use either `VALUES` or `SELECT`, not both.

Answer (score 0):

try by avoiding ' VALUES '

```
INSERT INTO edit_mdr (date_submitted, requestor, campus, defect_loc, defect_des, priority, action_taken, assigned_to, category, photo, status) 
    (SELECT submit_time,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-name',     field_value, NULL)) AS requestor,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'menu-campus',   field_value, NULL)) AS campus,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'location',      field_value, NULL)) AS defect_loc,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-message',  field_value, NULL)) AS defect_des,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'menu-priority', field_value, NULL)) AS priority,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'work_done',     field_value, NULL)) AS action_taken,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'assigned-to',   field_value, NULL)) AS assigned_to,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'category',      field_value, NULL)) AS category,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'file-photo',    field_value, NULL)) AS photo,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'status',        field_value, NULL)) AS status
FROM
    wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits
GROUP BY
    submit_time);
```

Comment: @Barmar , Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO edit_mdr (date_submitted, requestor, campus, defect_loc, defect_des, priority, action_taken, assigned_to, category, photo, status) 

      SELECT submit_time,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-name',     field_value, NULL)) AS requestor,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'menu-campus',   field_value, NULL)) AS campus,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'location',      field_value, NULL)) AS defect_loc,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-message',  field_value, NULL)) AS defect_des,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'menu-priority', field_value, NULL)) AS priority,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'work_done',     field_value, NULL)) AS action_taken,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'assigned-to',   field_value, NULL)) AS assigned_to,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'category',      field_value, NULL)) AS category,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'file-photo',    field_value, NULL)) AS photo,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'status',        field_value, NULL)) AS status
FROM
    wpc5_cf7dbplugin_submits
GROUP BY
    submit_time
;
```